# How to better control Emacs buffers in StumpWM?

Tags: buffers, frames, integration

I have been using Emacs more and more, to the point that I would like to start using StumpWM as my default window manager with it, so that I can integrate the missing bits of my workflow that realistically cannot (still) be done from inside Emacs alone. As the `EmacsWiki` puts it, "Stumpwm is the Emacs of window managers."

I have been trying Emacs from StumpWM, but I am going against a little 'context mismatch`, especially from controlling Emacs buffers in StumpWM.

I would like to match individual Emacs buffers as individual StumpWM frames. I thought perhaps one way would be to use Emacs' one-buffer-per-frame technique, but I am not sure it is a good way.

What kind of Emacs settings/libraries could be tweaked to better control Emacs buffers from StumpWM, so that each Emacs buffer corresponds to a StumpWM frame?

I do not experience this issue with other applications that I run from StumpWM, That is why I believe it is Emacs related, and I am asking it here on emacs.stackexchange.com

Thank you for any pointer.

Comment: I've been using StumpWM and Emacs for several years now, but I can't figure out what you're trying to do.  If you could give a more specific example in your question, I can probably answer it.

Comment: @purple-arrows: I would like to match individual Emacs buffers as individual StumpWM frames. I thought perhaps one way would be to use Emacs' one-buffer-per-frame technique, but I am not sure it is a good way?

Comment: I've never used one-buffer-per-frame, but if you get that working then you probably want to use Emacs hooks to give each (Emacs) frame its own title based on the buffer, then use (StumpWM) frame preference rules to place based on those titles.  Maybe?

Comment: Yes, thank you, that makes sense. I could use this, http://www.emacswiki.org/OneOnOneEmacs. Would you make it an answer, so that I can chose it? Also, would you consider pointing me to yours, or some other, dotfiles repo? Obviously that use case does not concern your workflow, but I am sure myself and others could benefit  from some other practical examples. Thank you.

Comment: I'm happy to write up an answer, but first could you rewrite the question above?  I'm unsure if I want this question to be on-topic here, and I think the beta community should have a chance to see it.

Comment: I have just rewritten it. Would that be all right now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17640/discussion-between-purple-arrows-and-gsl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are having difficulty with a new display manager.  This new display manager does not match your Emacs workflow.  We can try the following and see if it helps.

- pick up a frame-oriented workflow
- adjust the frame titles in appropriate ways, maybe with `(setq frame-title-format "%b")`
- configure the appropriate "frame preferences" in your display manager

Comment: `pick up a frame-oriented workflow` was the part I was missing. Thank you for that.